# class PCA matplotlib for face recognition

Tags: python, matplotlib, face-recognition, pca

I am trying to make face recognition by Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using python. I am using class `pca` found in `matplotlib`. Here is it's documentation:

> class matplotlib.mlab.PCA(a)
>      compute the SVD of a and store data for PCA. Use project to project the data onto a reduced set of dimensions
>
> ```
> Inputs:
> a: a numobservations x numdims array
> Attrs:
> a a centered unit sigma version of input a
> numrows, numcols: the dimensions of a
> mu : a numdims array of means of a
> sigma : a numdims array of atandard deviation of a
> fracs : the proportion of variance of each of the principal components
> Wt : the weight vector for projecting a numdims point or array into PCA space
> Y : a projected into PCA space
> ```

The factor loadings are in the Wt factor, ie the factor loadings for the 1st principal component are given by Wt[0]

And here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
import numpy.linalg as linalg
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA


#Step 1: put database images into a 2D array
filenames = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder/*.pgm')
filenames.sort()
img = [Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames]
images = np.asarray([np.array(im).flatten() for im in img])


#Step 2: database PCA
results = PCA(images.T)
w = results.Wt


#Step 3: input image
input_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\1.pgm').convert('L')
input_image = np.asarray(input_image)


#Step 4: input image PCA
results_in = PCA(input_image)
w_in = results_in.Wt


#Step 5: Euclidean distance
d = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.asarray(w - w_in)**2, axis=1))
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karim/Desktop/Bachelor 2/New folder/matplotlib_pca.py", line 32, in <module>
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.asarray(w - w_in)**2, axis=1))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,30) (92,92)
```

1. Can anyone help me to correct the error?
2. Is that the correct way for face recognition?

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the two arrays (`w` and `w_in`) are not the same size and `numpy` can not figure out how to broadcast the values to take the difference.

I am not familiar with this function, but I would guess that the source of the issue is your input images are different sizes.